# how to concate two strings to display on a combobox fetching data from a database

Tags: java

am developing a java application and I want to populate a ComboBox with First name and Last name from a table in database. how can I concatenate the two columns to display as one Full Name

this is my code. I will greatly appreciate for any assistance.

```
private void fillcombo(){
        try{ 
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password); 
          String sql = "select * From Member_Reg" ;
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();

          while(rs.next()){
              String name = rs.getString("First_name+""+Last_name");
              jComboBoxMembername.addItem(name);
          }

        }catch(Exception ex){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Get two `String`s out of the `ResultSet` and concatenate them in your Java code.

```
String name = rs.getString("First_name") + " " + rs.getString("Last_name");
```

It'd also be a really good idea to break that method up into multiple different ones - database access should be done in a different place to UI generation.

At a minimum this should be a method constructing your `jComboBoxMembername` variable (which seems to be global in your code at the moment, and it almost certainly shouldn't be), and that method should call a different method that retrieves the name from the database. So one method responsible for constructing the UI, and one method responsible for accessing the database. As your application gets bigger you'll want to separate them into different classes as well - a presentation class (or classes) and a database access class (or classes).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the first line inside the `while` loop with the following line:

```
String name = rs.getString("First_name") + " " + rs.getString("Last_name");
```